# Создать SQL запрос

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

Доброго времени суток. Начал изучать SQL, подскажите с запросом. Имеется таблица следующего вида:

```
CREATE TABLE expenses(
    num int,
    paydate date,
    receiver int,
    money dec
);

insert into expenses values (2, '25.10-2016', 1, 10000);
insert into expenses values (2, '12.06-2016', 2, 20500);
insert into expenses values (2, '27.02-2015', 1, 34500);
insert into expenses values (2, '27.02-2015', 1, 34500);
insert into expenses values (2, '27.02-2015', 2, 34500);
insert into expenses values (2, '27.02-2015', 1, 50500);
insert into expenses values (2, '27.02-2015', 1, 134500);
insert into expenses values (2, '08.09-2014', 3, 52000);
insert into expenses values (2, '08.09-2014', 3, 85000);
```

Требуется вывести наибольший платеж за тот день, когда сумма платежей была наибольшей.

Что насоставлял:

```
select max(money) from expenses where paydate = (select paydate from expenses where max(money) = (select sum(money) from expenses group by paydate));
```

Но где-то видимо допускаю ошибку. Подскажите, как поправить запрос?

Comment: `select max(money) from expenses where paydate = (select paydate from expenses group by paydate order by sum(money) desc limit 1)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
-- Получаем суммы по дням:
select 
     paydate
    ,sum(money) 
from expenses
group by paydate

-- Далее из этого самый простой вариант:
select max(money) from expenses where paydate = (
    select 
        paydate
    from expenses
    group by paydate
    order by sum(money) desc
    limit 0, 1
)
```

Comment: Спасибо! Буду разбираться как работает)